# Finding the value of an biased coin flip game with stop loss

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Question:
I have a biased coin, with 70% H and 30% T. I receive \$1 each time I flip a H and lose \$1 for T.

I am going to flip the coin 100 times, without any constraints, the expectation of money I will received will be \$40.

Now, what is the expectation if I stop once lose \$10?

My thoughts:
I model this as a random walk, $S_t = \sum_{i=1}^t Z_i$. And $\tau$ be the stopping time when $S_t$ reaches -10 for the first time. Our game stops at $\tau \wedge N$, where $N = 100$.

Now the expectation will be:

$\mathbb{E}[S_{\tau \wedge N}] = -10p + 40(1 - p)$, where $p = P(\tau\leq N)$

If the coin is unbiased, then $p$ can be found using reflection principle. Not sure how to find the distribution of $\tau$ for the biased coin. Any suggestions are welcome!

Edited: I just realized, if the coin is unbiased, then $S_{t\wedge N}$ will be a martingale and we can use optimal stoping theorem to get $\mathbb{E}[S_{\tau \wedge N}] = \mathbb{E}[S_0] \mathbb{E}[\tau \wedge N] = 0$. We can apply this theorem because $\tau \wedge N$ is also a stopping time and bounded.

Comment: The simple answer is that your expectation is still very close to $\$40$ as the chance of losing $\$10$ is very small.  It will be lower because the game is favorable so (from an expected value point of view) you want to play as much as possible and the stop loss will reduce the number of plays.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer (since I did not find a closed form for this probability and even suspect it may not exist at all), but here are my thoughts that may give you a better insight to the problem.

First, for a fixed $k$ and a fixed sum $S$ let us count the following probability

$$f(k, S) = P(z_1 + z_2 + \dots + z_k = S)$$

For all $S > k$ and $S < -k$ this probability is equal to 0. Note that $z_k$ is either $1$ or $-1$ with probabilities 0.7 and 0.3 respectively. Thus,

$$f(k, S) = 0.7f(k - 1, S - 1) + 0.3f(k - 1, S + 1)$$

This formula allows computing $f(k, S)$ recursively.

Then, for some $m > 0$:

$$p_m := P(\tau < N, \tau \geqslant m) = P(\tau < N, \tau \geqslant m | \tau = m)P(\tau = m) + P(\tau < N, \tau \geqslant m | \tau \geqslant m + 1)P(\tau \geqslant m + 1) = P(\tau < N | \tau = m)P(\tau = m) + P(\tau < N | \tau \geqslant m + 1)P(\tau \geqslant m + 1) = f(m, -10) + P(\tau < N, \tau \geqslant m + 1)(1-f(m, -10)) = \\ = f(m, -10) + (1-f(m, -10))p_{m+1}$$
As you can see, $p_m$ also can be counted recursively (but the closed form for $p_m$ can hardly be computed). The answer to your question is $p_1$.

Comment: The equality $$P(\tau<N\mid\tau\geq m)=P(\tau<N\mid\tau =m)P(\tau=m)+P(\tau<N\mid\tau\geq m+1)P(\tau\geq m+1)$$ is not true. You lost $P(\tau\geq m)$ in denominator of r.h.s.

Comment: @NCh According to law of total probability $P(\tau < N | \tau \geqslant m) = P(\tau < N | \tau \geqslant m, \tau = m) P(\tau = m) +P(\tau < N | \tau \geqslant m, \tau \geqslant m + 1) P(\tau \geqslant m + 1) $

Comment: This equality is not true too. R.h.s. is equal to $$P(\tau < N \mid \tau \geqslant m, \tau = m) P(\tau = m) +P(\tau < N \mid \tau \geqslant m, \tau \geqslant m + 1) P(\tau \geqslant m + 1)=\frac{P(\tau < N , \tau \geqslant m, \tau = m)}{P(\tau \geqslant m, \tau = m)} P(\tau = m) +\frac{P(\tau < N, \tau \geqslant m, \tau \geqslant m + 1)}{P(\tau \geqslant m, \tau \geqslant m + 1)} P(\tau \geqslant m + 1)=P(\tau < N , \tau \geqslant m, \tau = m)+P(\tau < N, \tau \geqslant m, \tau \geqslant m + 1)=P(\tau < N, \tau \geqslant m)\neq P(\tau < N\mid \tau \geqslant m).$$

Comment: @NCh Yes, good spot. Thank you, I replaced $P(\tau < N | \tau \geqslant m)$ with $P(\tau < N, \tau \geqslant m)$.